# ASP.NET MVC block a specific URL from the Default route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

In ASP.NET MVC route configuration is like below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I am using `[Route]` attribute in Controller:

```
[Route("login")]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
```

I can go to the page using both `/login` and `Auth/Login`. The second link is clearly from the default route, but I don't want that URL to go to my login page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To block a route from being served, you can use `IgnoreRoute` as long as you place it before the route you want to block:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute(url: "Auth/Login");

// Register any custom routes here...

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```